# .htaccess mod_rewrite not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I have a WordPress blog but I am having trouble trying to get mod_rewrite working with .htaccess.

Here's the content of .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)/all-comments/$ /$1/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I was trying to remove and truncate the /all-comments/ part of the URL which is at the end of URL with structure like http://www.mydomain.com/yyyy/mm/dd/random-text/all-comments/.

Apparently, the .htaccess allows the Wordpress permalinks to work correctly, but not the additional RewriteRules.

Anybody can help with the issue that custom mod_rewrite rules not been interprested in .htaccess?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Rule to:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\/all-comments\/$ /$1/
```

First parameter is regex so `/` should be written as `\/` :)